# SQL foreign key order of execution constraints

Tags: mysql

Is order of execution important when creating Primary/Foreign Key links in a MySQL statement?

For example, the following code will produce the error: "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Movies 
(
    MovieID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GenreID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(MovieID), 
    FOREIGN KEY(GenreID) References Genres(GenreID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Genres
(
    GenreID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GenreName   VARCHAR(30),
    Primary key (GenreID)
);
```

`Cannot add foreign key constraint`

But when the Genre table is created FIRST, the error no longer persists:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Genres
(
    GenreID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GenreName   VARCHAR(30),
    Primary key (GenreID)
);

CREATE TABLE Movies 
(
    MovieID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GenreID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(MovieID), 
    FOREIGN KEY(GenreID) References Genres(GenreID)
);
```

`Schema Ready`

Is the error caused because the table hasn't been created yet, so it doesn't know where / what the Genre tables PK type is?

When I was searching for a solution to foreign key constraints all I found was information on the data type matching, but not the order of execution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the error caused because the table hasn't been created yet, so it doesn't know where / what the Genre tables PK type is?

```
Yes.
```

If you define the `Movies` table first, MySQL is going to try to find the referenced `Genres` table, which does not yet exist.  So you should create them in the opposite order:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Genres
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Movies
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key is a reference to another key: primary key. If primary key doesn't exist now, you can not reference to an unknown thing, so you get exception.